# c++ system() function error

Tags: c++, windows, process, system

```
 void getresult(char * ip){
char * buf=new char[100];
const char * c=new char[100];
string cmd;
cmd="ping ";
cmd.append(ip);
cmd.append(" >pingresult.txt");
c=cmd.c_str();
system(c);
}
```

when i run the program in vs2012,there is no problem ,and the process is below [image]

but when i run the ping.exe(my program name) in the Debug f，there's an error "This file is in use by another program, the process cannot access"。 And the process is below [image]

the txt is  called by explore.exe and occupied.

Comment: You don't need to use `system()` for this at all.  Instead, you can send an ICMP echo request message directly using the network APIs.  How about that?

Comment: @John Zwinck  thanks,i know socket can do this ,but i want to know why the problem occured